# More than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression on on a simple query?

Tags: postgresql

This query:

```
SELECT "Nume", "Prenume" FROM public."Personal"
WHERE "Cod_angajat"=(SELECT "Cod_angajat" FROM public."Consultati");
```

Generates this error:

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
********** Error **********

ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
SQL state: 21000
```

There are two tables in the same database.  I'm going to kill my laptop because of this.  Is it because the query will return the same values twice or so?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `WHERE something = something_else` part requires that both `something` and `something_else` must be singular values of the same type.  SQL allows you to replace `something_else` with a subquery, but then this subquery must still return a singular value of the same type as `something`.

This means that your subquery must return one row containing one field.

Let me repeat this: your subquery must return one and only one row, and this row must contain one and only one field. Zero rows won't do it;  two or more rows won't do it;  two or more fields won't do it;  you need exactly one row, and exactly one field.

The error message says very clearly that your subquery returns more than one row.  Sometimes error messages are cryptic, so people come to stackoverflow to ask what they mean; this is not one of those cases.

As a matter of fact, your query does not have any filter, (no `WHERE` clause,) so ***it returns all rows in the table.***

That will clearly not work.

You need to restate your subquery so that it returns only one row.